# How to get country list array with their corresponding country codes

Tags: 8, location

I have used `$countries = \Drupal\Core\Locale\CountryManager::getStandardList();` to render array of countries with country code as their keys. But when I debug the variable `$countries;` `print_r($countries);die;` it goes into infinite loop and result does not get rendered. It shows 404.

How to get country list array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the infinite loop, because the country name is a translatable markup and print_r() can't handle this object. If you cast the country name to a string, then it is printable in php:

```
 $countries = \Drupal\Core\Locale\CountryManager::getStandardList();
 foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
   $country_name = (string) $value;
   print "$key - $country_name\n";
 }
```

This is not needed for rendering, because twig can handle this object. This is only for debugging.

Comment: How can I get list of states for a particular country?

Answer (score 2):

`$countries = \Drupal\Core\Locale\CountryManager::getStandardList();
 foreach ($countries as $key => $value) {
   $countries[$key] = $value->__toString();
 }`
$countries will return the array.

Answer (score 0):

While the other answers return you the country list, the list might not be complete. The `CountryManager` class also provides a different function `getList()`. It returns the standard list that is returned by the static function `getStandardList()`, and allows other modules to add/alter the countries in the list.

Luckily, the `CountryManager` is also registered as a service and can be used as follows:

```
$country_manager = \Drupal::service('country_manager');
$list = $country_manager->getList();
$countries = [];
foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
  $val = $value->__toString();
  $countries[$key] = $val;
}
// $countries - will contain key-valued paid of country code and name.
```

If you are using this in the controller, or any other service, it is recommended to properly inject the service following dependency injection pattern.