# D8 Webforms Predefined Options

Tags: webforms

How would you use/access D8 Webforms Predefined Options (such as days,months,gender, marital status,country etc,etc) in code, say in MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, FormStateInterface $form_state, $form_id). Where is the predefined options data stored ?

For example, for country codes options ["AF"=>"Afghanistan","AL"=>"Albania",....,"US"=>"United States",..] how would you get country name from country code.

Your aasistance will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can alter the options in this hook:

```
/**
 * Alter form options by id.
 *
 * @param array $options
 *   An associative array of options.
 * @param array $element
 *   The form element that the options is for.
 * @param string $options_id
 *   The form options id. Set to NULL if the options are custom.
 */
function hook_webform_options_alter(array &$options, array &$element, $options_id = NULL) {
```

See http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/webform.api.php

The options are stored in the config entity `webform_options`, see http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/src/Entity/WebformOptions.php

Comment: can have **hook_webform_options_alter** in my custom module ?Check I have edited my question for clarity

Comment: The example you've added is not a good example, because Webform doesn't store country names (only if you edit them), instead it gets the country names from the service CountryManager. You can do the same, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/222834/how-to-get-country-list-array-with-their-corresponding-country-codes

Comment: No check any recent version of webform has country_codes as one of predifined options just like gender,education,marital status etc etc mention it.

Comment: See webform_webform_options_country_names_alter() in http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform/tree/includes/webform.options.inc

Comment: In fact country codes was just an example. Any webforms predefined option has key value pair. So in general sense how would I get the value if I known its key, that is, from code.

Comment: Use the entity mentioned in the answer and an example where the values are stored in Webform like Months: \Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformOptions::load('months')->getOptions()

Comment: I was about to accept this as the right answer but to my surprise it does not work for other predefined options such as country_codes,country_names. They output an empty array. Any idea why this is so. I am using machine name as id for the entity.

Comment: I'm telling you this from the beginning when you brought up this example. Webform doesn't store this data. Look at the webform code linked in a  previous comment.

Answer (score -1):

`use use Drupal\webform\Entity\WebformOptions;
// **ID of option = country_code or gender** 
 $webform_test_options = WebformOptions::load('ID of option');
 $options = $webform_test_options->getOptions();

 /* Update predefind options --- */

$webform_test_options->set('options', Yaml::encode($data));
/* $data will be array ["AF"=>"Afghanistan","AL"=>"Albania",....,"US"=>"United States",..]*/ $webform_test_options->save();`

Hope this help.